# Adding extra product to cart with dropdown in product detail page

Tags: product, cart, ce-1.8.1.0

There will be some products that are selectable on my product detail page which you can add cart with a dropdown. I mean there will be 2 products in cart.  Maybe the customer doesnt want to add product on dropdown.

[image]

How can I add some products on the dropdown in product detail page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always add more items to cart using the related_products field. You can take a look better in checkout/cart/add controller...

You can try it in your product view page something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="related_product" value="a valid product id here" />
```

This will add your current product and the one specified in the hidden field... U can use your select field normally just having the values as the product ids you want to use.

Comment: Your way worked very well, thanks. Can I do that with dropdown?

Comment: @ibrahim. Please mark this answer as selected if it solved your problem.